# Neo4j browser is getting disconnected frequenty from the server

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4J 2.1.0 M01 64bit community edition on 64bit windows machine. So whenever i execute cypher queries it shows " **disconnected from neo4j: please check if the cord is unpluged"**. When i searched for the same issue in the net ,they are saying to do some settings in the `neo4j.properties` file present in the `conf` folder.So what changes needs to be done to file?

My `neo4j.properties` content is :

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
#neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=25M
#neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=50M
#neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=90M
#neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=130M
#neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=130M
```

Here everything is commented out by default.

Please tell me what's needs to be done to resolve this issue?

Thanks,
Shree

Comment: Try upgrading to 2.1.2. There was a bug in 2.1 which made the browser UI check too frequently if server is available. I'm not sure when it was introduced but it was fixed and included in the release 2.1.2.

Comment: So upgrading to 2.1.2 will alone solve the problem or do we need to configure anything in the neo4j.properties.com because earlier when i installed 2.1.0 version. Recently i started showing this kind of message.

Comment: Also can i install 2.1.2 32bit installer on 64 bit windows machine??? Does this cause any performance issues as i dint find 2.1.2 64bit installer.

Comment: I believe just installing 2.1.2 should fix the issue.